# Why does it duplicate my database entry when updating the information?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When I try to update the `ID` in my database it then save the information but saves over the previous `ID` information as well.

So this is what I am doing:

I have `GrdiView` with an `Edit` button:

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Edit"
  DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-success"
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Edit.aspx?id={0}" />
```

This then opens the `Edit` page where I can see the information from that `ID` in the `TextBoxes`

**EDIT.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["UserName"] != null)
            {
                this.WelcomeBackMessage.Text = string.Format("Welcome {0}", Session["UserName"].ToString());
                this.WelcomeBackMessage1.Text = string.Format(Session["UserName"].ToString());
                this.WelcomeBackMessage2.Text = string.Format(Session["UserName"].ToString());
            }
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteInfoConnection"].ConnectionString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con1.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand($"SELECT [Id], " +
                $"[Company name] AS Company_name, " +
                $"[Branch], " +
                $"[Company Website] AS Company_Website, " +
                $"[Contact Person] AS Contact_Person, " +
                $"[Telephone Number] AS Telephone_Number, " +
                $"[Fax], " +
                $"[Physical Address] AS Physical_Address, " +
                $"[GPS], " +
                $"[Notes] FROM [ClientInformation] WHERE ID={Request["id"]}", con1);

            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                CompanyName.Text = (myReader["Company_name"].ToString());
                Branch.Text = (myReader["Branch"].ToString());
                CompanyWebsites.Text = (myReader["Company_Website"].ToString());
                ContactPerson.Text = (myReader["Contact_Person"].ToString());
                TelephoneNumber.Text = (myReader["Telephone_Number"].ToString());
                Fax.Text = (myReader["Fax"].ToString());
                PhysicalAddress.Text = (myReader["Physical_Address"].ToString());
                GPS.Text = (myReader["GPS"].ToString());
                Notes.Text = (myReader["Notes"].ToString());
            }
            con1.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void EditToSql(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteInfoConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ClientInformation SET [Company name] = @CompName, " +
            "[Branch] = @CompBranch, " +
            "[Company Website] = @CompWebsite, " +
            "[Contact Person] = @CompPerson, " +
            "[Telephone Number] = @CompNumber, " +
            "[Fax] = @CompFax, " +
            "[Physical Address] = @CompAddress, " +
            "[GPS] = @CompGPS, " +
            "[Notes] = @CompNotes WHERE ID= 'id'", con);
        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName", CompanyName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompBranch", Branch.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompWebsite", CompanyWebsites.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompPerson", ContactPerson.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompNumber", TelephoneNumber.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompFax", Fax.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompAddress", PhysicalAddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompGPS", GPS.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompNotes", Notes.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Now When I update the information it saves it to the database but it overrides the previous entry.

Example:

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID | Column 1  | Column 2  | Column 3  |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | Test Data | Test Data | Test Data |
------------------------------------------
| 2  | Test Data | Test Data | Test Data |
------------------------------------------
```

When Selecting `ID` 2 and update the information to "New Text" it then does the following:

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID | Column 1  | Column 2  | Column 3  |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | New Text  | New Text  | New Text  |
------------------------------------------
| 2  | New Text  | New Text  | New Text  |
------------------------------------------
```

Not sure why this is doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to learn how to use the WHERE sql statement

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: *Can you please explain?* where is where in update?

Comment: Without a where clause - you will update the entire table

Comment: If you omit the WHERE clause in an UPDATE statement you update every record of your table. Adding a WHERE clause you could choose the record to update

Comment: With a cursor you can do UPDATE WHERE CURRENT, to update the recently fetched row only.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have updated my question but stil not working :-(

Comment: Now you have this problem. The 'id' is just a string. The Where cannot find anything in the column ID that contains the string 'id'. Instead you should add another parameter with the ID value that you want to search for. However you need to read that ID from your previous query and store it somewhere. You can even use an hidden textbox that you fill with the ID value

Answer (score 1):

This line looks suspect, as the id will always be "id".

```
"[Notes] = @CompNotes WHERE ID= 'id'", con);
```

I'm not sure what datatype your id column is, but I wouldn't be surprised if this doesn't work at all.  At the very least, this problem should be evident when looking at the data.  Did you provide us with the latest version of the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following changes:

1. First you need to read ID while fetching data. Based on you code structure store ID.
2. Fix the update statement in this way:
   `"[Notes] = @CompNotes WHERE ID= @ID", con);`
3. Add the `@ID` parameter and pass the ID value stored in first step.
   `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);`

This should fix it.